# Limiting the number of "Instance on Points" in the Viewport

Tags: 3d-view, particles, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm having trouble with the unresponsive viewport due to the number of "Distributed Particles on Point" displayed by the geometry node setup. It displays the mesh ("foam particle" AKA icosphere) on every single point.

Using the "Is Viewport" node is probably the solution, but I'm not sure how to connect it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a setup like this:

[image]

It allows you to reduce the density by **not** spawning $x$ out of every $n$ points, here $n = 9$, and $x$ is the value I change.

Answer (score 0):

Is viewport works best plugged into a switch node.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9AL1.png]

Comment: If I do this it shows nothing in the viewport. I'm distributing the particles on Points (alembic sequence), there are no faces. So could the node "Distribute points on faces" be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were using an allembic. Yes distribute points won't work in that case.